# mysql command line client says can't connect to Azure Database for Mysql

Tags: azure-database-mysql

I was happily using mysql command line in my mac to connect Azure Database for MySql. But all of sudden it started throwing an error saying:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXXXXXXX.mysql.database.azure.com' (61)
```

I can see the the database instances is running alright, as I'm able to use the database from an application that is running in Azure.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Have you specified the user name using the "user@servername" convention?

Comment: yes , i was using the right convention. I have posted an answer for this already. Thanks for taking time out to comment on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred because the particular network i was connected to not allowing any such connections. Later when i tried from my usual network ( home / office )it got connected. I haven't made any changes in my Azure Db for MySql nor in my local machine, this proves that problem was with that particular network.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like firewall rules were not setup for that specific network.  Can you confirm by looking at this doc?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-firewall-rules

Basically, you can click "Add my IP" which would add your current network's Client IP.  However, if the network you are on SNAT's out with multiple IP's, you would need to add the entire range from your networking team.

Thanks.

James